# What is the term for changing the relationship in a document

Tags: grammar, structure

The example is in the question: What is the term for changing the relationship in a document, as in "We see that you are..." and later in the same document "I want you to ..."?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're thinking of [pronoun shift](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/gram_pronoun_shifts.html). You can of course use different pronouns in one document, but only if they mean different things ("**I** wrote this article last week. I also wrote another with my friend Jim; **we** said..."). But if, say, you use "I" and "we" interchangeably to refer to whoever is writing, or if you use "you" or "one" to refer to the reader, these should be made consistent.

A bigger problem is when a pronoun doesn't match its antecedent, but that's usually within the space of only a few sentences.